# Backbone collection.create() does not return the updated model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

To learn backbone Im creating a Twitter like app. So you know that Twitter sends a GET request to the server every N seconds to check for new tweets. If there are new tweets, it creates the hidden *li* elements and shows the button with "N new Tweets". If you click it, it shows the hidden *li* elements, showing the new tweets.
But the behaviour is different when you add a new tweet: the tweet is visible. You don't have to click the button to see it.

I already have made the first part, for the hidden tweets. For the part of posting a new tweet and showing it direclty, I thought it would be easy to do by creating the new model, calling collection.create() and triggering the right event, something like:

```
var newTweet = new Tweet();
newTweet.set( /* set the attributes here. Some attributes are missing, because they are calculated server side */ );

var created_tweet = this.collection.create( newTweet, { silent: true, wait: true } ); // I choose silent=true because the add event on my collection is in charge of adding the new hidden tweets when there are new ones on the server
this.collection.trigger("posted_new_tweet", created_tweet);
```

Then, my collection is subscribed to the event "posted_new_tweet", so every time a user posts a new tweet, a specific method of my collection is being called.
This approach was working fine until I got errors due to the variable created_comment passed in the trigger: it is not "complete". I mean that the model has some attributes like *"id"* or *"created_on"* that are  undefined. These attributes are calculated server side, but I thought that if I passed **wait=true**, it would wait and update my model with the response given by the server (when a **POST** request is made to the server, it returns the new created model in json)

Shouldn't my model have the server side attributes aswell? Is it the right approach for such a thing? In case that it is not, how can I have 2 different methods to display a collection view?

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`create` is still asynchronous even if you pass `{ wait: true }`. The difference is without `wait` the model will get added to the collection immediately  while with `wait` backbone won't add it to the collection until a success response from the server.

What you should do is add a success callback to `create` that fires the event upon the server response.

```
var created_tweet = this.collection.create( newTweet, { silent: true, wait: true, success: this.successCallback } );

// Add successCallback as a method to the collection
successCallback: function(collection, response) {
  // I'm not 100% positive which values are passed to this function. Collection may actually be the new model.
  this.collection.trigger("posted_new_tweet", created_tweet);
}
```

Comment: I believe that in the later versions of Backbone, the arguments are now `nextModel` and `response`.