# Backbonejs collection.create: how to prevent it from adding items if there is an error?

Tags: validation, jquery, backbone.js

How can I prevent `collection.create` from adding items into its collection if there is an error found in the input?

html,

```
<div id="new-status">
      <h2>New monolog</h2>
      <form action="">
        <textarea name="content"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Post">
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="statuses">
      <h2>Monologs</h2>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
```

backbone,

```
var Status = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){

    },
    validate: function(attrs, options) {
        if(attrs.text === '') alert("please enter some text");
    },
    url:"dummy.php",
    sync: function (method, model, options) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'server.php', 
            data: {
                text: this.get("text")
            }
        });
    }
});

var Statuses = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Status
});

var NewStatusView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        "submit form": "addStatus"
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
         _.bindAll(this, 'addStatus', 'clearInput');
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.clearInput) ;
    },

    addStatus: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.collection.create({ text: this.$('textarea').val() });
    },

    clearInput: function() {
        this.$('textarea').val('');
    }
});

var StatusesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.collection.on("add", this.appendStatus, this);
    },

    appendStatus: function(status) {
        this.$('ul').append('<li>' + status.escape("text") + '</li>');
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var statuses = new Statuses();
    new NewStatusView({ el: $('#new-status'), collection: statuses });
    new StatusesView({ el: $('#statuses'), collection: statuses });
});
```

So, when you hit the submit button without typing any text, you get an error popup from this part in the model,

```
validate: function(attrs, options) {
            if(attrs.text === '') alert("please enter some text");
        },
```

But how can I **tell the collection** that there is an error and **do not add** this empty item and also **do not fire** `sync` in the model?

**EDIT:**

got it worked with `collection.create` in this way...

model,

```
validate: function(attrs, options) {
    if(attrs.text === '') {
        var message = "please enter some text";
        alert(message);
        return message;
    }
},
```

view,

```
addStatus: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var one = new Status({ text: this.$('textarea').val() });

        if (!one.isValid()) {
            alert(one.validationError);
        } else {
            this.collection.create(one);
        }

    },
```

it seems to work fine unless it is not a good approach or against MVC pattern?

Comment: You should `return` the error and listen to `invalid` event.

Comment: how can i return the error and listen?

Comment: By using `return` keyword, if your don't return the error the validation doesn't validate the Model properly, the error is passed to the `invalid` handler, there you can `alert` it.

Comment: I usually validate the inputs before creating a Model.

Comment: So you validate the inputs in the `view` not in the `model`?

Comment: Yes, I validate them in my views. My Models don't have `validate` function :)

Comment: I thought validation is the job of a model as a MVC pattern would say...?

Comment: Yes, I do this on the server, for Backbone I create a Modal View which  is generated dynamically and does the validation.

Comment: Yes, I prefer doing the validation on server side as well.

Comment: `create` will return the `model`. So you could do, `var model = this.collection.create(attributes,{wait:true});`. Then alert if `model.validationError` is defined, you still have to return some text from your `model`'s `validate` function though, as others have said.

Comment: thanks. can you show some examples how this is done please?

Comment: `create` will instantiate a model,save it to the server, and add it to the collection, but it sounds like you are just wanting to add the new `model` to the collection without saving it to the server, could you clarify?

Comment: no, I want to validate it before saving it to the server. and I prefer doing the validation over the server. so maybe `wait` is a good solution I think! I came across this Q&A but I still dunno hwo to make it worked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047465/backbone-collection-create-does-not-return-the-updated-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think collection.create is the right choice here.

```
addStatus: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var status = new Status({"text": this.$('textarea').val()})
    var error = status.valiate();
    if(!error) {
        this.collection.add(status);  
    } 
},
```

Also not that the backbone [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate) says this about `validate`:

> If the attributes are valid, don't return anything from validate; if
>   they are invalid, return an error of your choosing. It can be as
>   simple as a string error message to be displayed, or a complete error
>   object that describes the error programmatically.

So, your validate function should be fixed:

```
validate: function(attrs, options) {
    if(attrs.text === '') {
        var message = "please enter some text";
        alert(message);
        return message;
    }
},
```

Comment: You can also use `isValid()` method which runs the `validate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Model's` `validate` method should return an `error` string so that models save is not fired in case of alert.

```
validate: function(attrs, options) {
    if(attrs.text === ''){
      alert("please enter some text");
      return "Text is empty."; // OR proper error CODE
    }
}
```

Check [validate](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate) method of `Backbone.Model`.