# add updated model into Backbone Collections

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I used `collection create` method to save the model into the server. But this `create` method automatically adds the `stale model` into the `collection`.

I am trying to do the following things.

- After the inserting process success, I would like to add `updated
  model` into the collection. The updated info is returned from server
  as a `json`.
- If the server responses `error`, I don't want to add the `model` into the
  `collection`.

Do I need to extend the `collection create` method? Or is there another way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backbone collection.create() does not return the updated model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047465/backbone-collection-create-does-not-return-the-updated-model). I think that thread answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> Creating a model will cause an immediate "add" event to be triggered on the collection, a "request" event as the new model is sent to the server, as well as a "sync" event, once the server has responded with the successful creation of the model. **Pass {wait: true} if you'd like to wait for the server before adding the new model to the collection**.

(*emphasis mine*)

That'll look like:

```
collection.create({ // attributes
},{wait: true});
```